Intramolecular hydrogen bonding in 2-amino benzaldehyde?
If hydrogen bonding is there, then what is the effect of intramolecular hydrogen bonding on dipole moment of 2-aminobenzaldehyde and 4-aminobenzaldehyde? Their dipole moment values?

